# Haskell Function that Takes a List of Pairs and A list and Returns a List

Tags: list, haskell

I have to write a haskell function that does the following:

`mySub` that takes a list of pairs and a list of values and returns a new list
where each occurrence of the first value in a pair is replaced by the second value in the
pair. The replacement should occur in order of pairs. E.g., `mySub [('a','b'), ('c','d')]`
"abcd" should give "bbdd" and `mySub [(1,2), (2,3)] [1,2,3,4]` should give `[3,3,3,4]`.

I am not even sure where to start on this one.

Comment: This is your 3rd homework question in an hour... We're not here to do homework for you.

Comment: All these homework problems are related. Take an hour, look at the answers to your other questions, and you should be able to solve this one on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try solving this problem first: write a function `oneSub` that takes a tuple and a list and replaces each element in the list that is equal to the first element in the tuple with the second element.  So `oneSub ('h','c') "hat"` would evaluate to `"cat"`.

One you write this function, try to use it to implement `mySub`